# Make stars blink in Pygame

Tags: python

The following code generates random x,y coordinates, appending the coordinates to a list, then runs a for-loop through the list to blit star images to the screen. The same stars are constantly being redrawn while the code is running, but they're in the same location, so the screen looks static. Here is the code.

```
import time
import pygame
from random import randint
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("My God, it's full of stars!")

med_star_img = pygame.image.load('images/medium_star.png')
tiny_star_img = pygame.image.load('images/tiny_star.png')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
gray = (50,50,50)

tiny_stars_width = tiny_star_img.get_width()
tiny_stars_height = tiny_star_img.get_height()

med_stars_width = med_star_img.get_width()
med_stars_height = med_star_img.get_height()

tiny_stars_location = []
med_stars_location = []

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
gameDisplay.fill(gray)

# create random coordinates for stars
for i in range(25):
        tiny_stars_location.append(pygame.Rect(randint(1,800),randint(1,600),tiny_stars_width,tiny_stars_height))

for i in range(10):
        med_stars_location.append(pygame.Rect(randint(1,800),randint(1,600),med_stars_width,med_stars_height))


def make_med_star(x,y):
        gameDisplay.blit(med_star_img, (x,y))
        
def make_tiny_star(x,y):
        gameDisplay.blit(tiny_star_img, (x,y))
        
while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        running = False
                        
        for star in med_stars_location:
                make_med_star(star.x,star.y)
                
        for star in tiny_stars_location:
                make_tiny_star(star.x,star.y)
                
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(1)
        clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I'd like the stars to occasionally blink, which I think would be done by randomly removing one or two stars from the stars_location list during the main loop before adding them back when the loop comes back around. The loop probably executes very fast, but I think I can add a delay. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a boolean for each star. If the value is True the star is visible.

Example for saving star data: (I wouldn't use the `pygame.Rect` and instead a simple list)

```
for i in range(25):
    tiny_stars_location.append([randint(1,800),randint(1,600),tiny_stars_width,tiny_stars_height, True])
```

Also you should not use `time.sleep` in a pygame program. It does not delay a task. I delays the program. So you have to wait a whole second to close the program or interact with it in any way.

A lazy but working approach would be just to use randomness. You could just get a random number with `random.randint(0, n)`, if it is 0 you set the boolean value of the star to True or False, depending on what state it currently is. You can set the variable `n` to some number like

n = maximum fps * average seconds before the star is hidden/shown

An other thing you probably just forgot is to clear the window in the loop with `gameDisplay.fill(gray)`.

Your finished code could look like this:

```
import time
import pygame
from random import randint
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("My God, it's full of stars!")

med_star_img = pygame.image.load('images/medium_star.png')
tiny_star_img = pygame.image.load('images/tiny_star.png')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
gray = (50,50,50)

tiny_stars_width = tiny_star_img.get_width()
tiny_stars_height = tiny_star_img.get_height()

med_stars_width = med_star_img.get_width()
med_stars_height = med_star_img.get_height()

tiny_stars_location = []
med_stars_location = []

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
gameDisplay.fill(gray)

# create random coordinates for stars
for i in range(25):
        tiny_stars_location.append([randint(1,800),randint(1,600),tiny_stars_width,tiny_stars_height, True])

for i in range(10):
        med_stars_location.append([randint(1,800),randint(1,600),med_stars_width,med_stars_height, True])


def make_med_star(x,y):
        gameDisplay.blit(med_star_img, (x,y))
        
def make_tiny_star(x,y):
        gameDisplay.blit(tiny_star_img, (x,y))
        
while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        running = False

        
        for star in med_stars_location:
            if star[2]:
                make_med_star(star[0], star[1])
            if not randint(0, 300): # 300 / 60(fps) = 5  -> every 5 seconds on average
                star[2] = not star[2] # inverse
                
        for star in tiny_stars_location:
            if star[2]:
                make_tiny_star(star[0], star[1])
            if not randint(0, 300): # 300 / 60(fps) = 5  -> every 5 seconds on average
                star[2] = not star[2] # inverse
        
                
        pygame.display.flip()
        #time.sleep(1) <- never do this in pygame
        clock.tick(60)
        gameDisplay.fill(gray) # reset display

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Can we make it so the stars don't stay hidden for so long? I'd like them to occasionally blink off and then come back on again very quickly. That would be more the effect I'm going for. Otherwise, I really like the solution.

Comment: You could split it in two. disappear: `if not randint(0, 60 * seconds): star[2] = False` and appear: `if not randint(0, 60 * seconds): star[2] = True`

Comment: It works great like this:
if not randint(0, 600): star[2] = False
if not randint(0, 5): star[2] = True
Very cool.

Comment: Otherwise, I don't understand your use of 'seconds'.